# hidden form to save aggregated values to model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating a small django invoicing system for my first python project and I am stuck on this rather large issue handling data. I have a hierarchy of models that I use to easily input the data from paper. I have "services", which are migrated to "invoice", which are then migrated to "Bill Period" that the user will view all of their services provided for that month. The code will explain it better. What I need is a final model with an "Agency To Bill" and "Total" fields with a "Paid" booleanfield so I can keep track of payments and use these value with django-authorizenet. Using models is still new for me, so I'm stumped on how to do this. I am thinking that when the user views the invoice-detail page, a hidden form will be submitted with the cost values added together.

```
# models.py tiers
# compiled invoice with sum of all "cost" in
# bill period would be the last step
class Service(models.Model):
    name_of_service = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    cost            = models.CharField(max_length="50")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name_of_service)

class Bill_Period(models.Model):
    start_date      = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date        = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.start_date)

class invoice(models.Model):
    date_of_service     = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now(),blank=True)
    agency_to_bill      = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
    patient             = models.ForeignKey('users.Patient', blank=True)
    therapy_completed   = models.ForeignKey('Service', blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.agency_to_bill)

class compiled_invoice(models.Model):
# month, total, paid



# views.py i use to handle the information
# error message "Relation fields do not support nested lookups"
def InvoiceDetail(request, month, year): 
current_user = request.user
invoice_detail = invoice.objects.filter(date_of_service__year=year, 
                                        date_of_service__month=month, 
                                        agency_to_bill=current_user)
c = invoice.objects.filter(paid=False, 
                            date_of_service__year=year,
                            date_of_service__month=month,
                            agency_to_bill=current_user)
total = invoice.objects.filter(therapy_completed__Service__cost__isnull=True).aggregate(Sum('cost'))
return render_to_response('invoice-detail.html', {'invoice_detail': invoice_detail,
                                                    'current_user': current_user,
                                                    'month': month,
                                                    })
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated, because at this point I'm stuck. This hidden form is my last ditch effort.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want a hidden form. Why not just create the object directly in the view?

Comment: I tried to aggregate the 'cost' values in the view, but had no success. I posted the error above the view